# iOS: How to assert a cell is selected in UITest?

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode-ui-testing, uitest

I have the following hierarchy:
ViewController -> TableView -> TableViewCell -> CollectionView -> CollectionViewCell -> UIImage

On the tableViewCell, inside the collectionView, there are 4 cells. Each cell has a unique label.

When the user taps the collectionViewCell the cell becomes selected and also the UIImageView is highlighted. In this case this means there is a different image there. I have the accessibility on the UIImageView enabled and the traits set to both button and image to try to access those XCUIElementTypes

I have not been able to make any UITest work because it always tells me that there are multiple results for the UIImageView even though the cell that the image view is in has a unique identifier.

How do I assert that the cell has been selected?

Using the record function I get:
`let whatIsYourFilingStatusCellsQuery = XCUIApplication().tables.cells.containingType(.StaticText, identifier:"Single").childrenMatchingType(.Image).matchingIdentifier("btn_unselected").tap()`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I really dont have pretty solution. But I see there is only one way to assert cell is selected. Set some property to the cell at the moment of selecting. E.g accessibilityIdentifier is going to have unique id, and accessibilityValue is going to have any info what you need ("selected=true" or "selected")

UPD you have access for these properties:

[image]

Comment: For me at least, selected doesn't work, it's not one of the XCUIElement properties. Have you tried this solution before? But maybe if I make the accessibility label change then I can check for the existance of the "new" element? I'll think more about this...

Comment: I mean not `XCUIElement.selected`. I mean that in your **app code** set `yourElement.accessibilityValue = @"selected=true"`; You can get this value from **test code** like `yourXCUIelement.value`. Look at [Understanding accessibility on iOS link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Accessibility_on_iPhone/Accessibility_on_iPhone.html)

Comment: Oh you didn't mean the selected state you meant to set the accessibility label. That is a good idea, I'm not sure if it will be possible but I will try that when I finish debugging some other problems. What did you mean "UDP" in your post? I don't know that term. I don't think we have access to all of those properties but most of them, yep. These are the element attributes you can use in UITest: http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/Protocols/XCUIElementAttributes.html

Comment: UPD=Update(post) :)  i am convinced that we have access to accessibility id, value, description at least (because i use them)

Comment: You should not follow this advice. `accessibilityValue` is used for actual accessibility ([see the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615117-accessibilityvalue)). The only thing listed under accessibility that should be used for development purposes like this is the identifier.

Comment: I think accessibilityIdentifier should be static.

Answer (score 1):

@Che has the right idea.

In `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`, I did this:

```
cell.accessibilityIdentifier = @"isSelected";
```

Then, in the test file:

```
XCTAssertEqualObjects(randomCellToTap.value, @"isSelected");
```

I'm also going to do the opposite thin in `didDeselect...`

Comment: You should not follow this advice. `accessibilityValue` is used for actual accessibility ([see the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615117-accessibilityvalue)). The only thing listed under accessibility that should be used for development purposes like this is the identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Add the selection state to the `accessibilityTraits`, like this:

```
cell.accessibilityTraits = [.button, .selected]
```

Then in the ***UITest*** you can check if the `cell.isSelected` state, also this will reduce the complexity for programming *voice over* states.

The other solutions will require you to implement the voice over state manually.

Answer (score 0):

If SwiftUI:

```
VStack {
    ZStack {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
        if index == selectedIndex {
            Image(decorative: "ic_check")
        }
    }
    Text("ブルー")
}
.onTapGesture {
    selectedIndex = index
}
.accessibilityAddTraits(index == selectedIndex ? [.isSelected, .isButton] : .isButton)
```

Even more you can merge the children.

```
HStack {
    Image("ic_comment", label: Text("コメント数"))
    Text("10")
}
.accessibilityElement(children: .combine)
.accessibilityIdentifier("your id")
.accessibilityAddTraits(index == selectedIndex ? [.isSelected, .isButton] : [.isButton] )
```

I found it from [here](https://qiita.com/rakuma_devrel/items/935af0a7c624e40f168f)